# Is use of 'by' required before empathic pronoun

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, reflexive-pronouns, emphasis

"Did Simone fix her car **by** herself?

Is **by** required in above line?What will be change in sense if **by** is omitted?

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical but there is a slight difference in meaning; in particular each one implies a different *alternative* to Simone fixing the car alone.

"Did Simone fix the car by herself?" asks whether Simone fixed the car alone, and alternative would be if someone had assisted her.  If you wanted to really emphasize this meaning, you could ask, "Did Simone fix the car **all by** herself?"

"Did Simone fix the car herself?" asks whether Simone fixed the car, and the alternative would be if else did it and she didn't do any of the work herself.

Expanding each version to make the implied alternative explicit:

> Did Simone **fix the car by herself** or did she get some help from her brother?
>
> Did Simone **fix the car herself** or did she send it to the mechanic for repairs?